# My WordPress site redirects to port 8082

Tags: redirect

I have a wp site that was working on a dev server on port 8082.
After we decided the site is done, we transferred it to another server. However something in the site redirects to 8082 despite the fact that the nginx configuration is pointing to 80. This is madness. I've tried to point it to another port i.e. 8085 but it still reverts back to 8082 and times out because the nginx is not configured on that port.
It is a clean WP install with one of the default themes and there are no plugins.

I have also tried to put the bellow eddits to wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://example.name');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.name');
```

And eddied the `siteurl` and and `home` fields into the `wp_options` table but the site still redirects to port 8082

Any suggestions?

Comment: Usually after changing a port it's customary to restart the httpd server

Comment: That is what I did. This is a very unique case. I administer Linux servers for several years I've seen nothing like this, pure madness ..

Comment: Did you transfer the site to another server or it's a clean install? You mention both. Does it redirect you immediately from any URL or after you followed any link? Do you use a caching plugin? Nothing is clear from you question.

Comment: What is the home page URL in Settings | General. Have you added a port to it there? Perhaps your .htaccess file is doing some rewriting. Also check wp-config.php.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at my answer here :

[Stackechange redirects all pages from new domain to old domain](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/264246/wp-redirects-all-pages-from-new-domain-to-old-domain/264258#264258)

Otherwise check the .htaccess files also